# Display image on root page of the notebook in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am designing a GUI window for my project. In that I want to display a image on the notebook root page (so that although any tab is active, image is seen) I have programmed in python using tkinter. I didnt find the way for adding image on root page.
code is below:

```
title = 'Trial Tool window'

# Import Pmw from this directory tree.
import sys
sys.path[:0] = ['../../..']

import Tkinter
import Pmw

class MyButton(Tkinter.Button):
    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        self.__toggle = 0
        apply(Tkinter.Button.__init__, (self, master, cnf), kw)

class Demo:
    def __init__(self, parent):
    # Create and pack the NoteBook.
        notebook = Pmw.NoteBook(parent)
        notebook.pack(fill = 'both', expand = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

        page = notebook.add('AAAA')
        notebook.tab('AAAA').focus_set()

        # Create the "Toolbar" contents of the page.
        group = Pmw.Group(page, tag_text = 'XYZ')
        group.pack(fill = 'both', expand = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        b1 = Tkinter.Checkbutton(group.interior(), text = 'Show tool')
        b1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        # Add all other Channel pages.
        page = notebook.add('BBBB')
        page = notebook.add('CCCC')
        page = notebook.add('DDDD')
        page = notebook.add('EEEE')
        page = notebook.add('FFFF')
        page = notebook.add('GGGG')
        page = notebook.add('HHHH')
        page = notebook.add('IIII')
        page = notebook.add('JJJJ')
        page = notebook.add('KKKK')
        page = notebook.add('LLLL')
        page = notebook.add('MMMM')
        page = notebook.add('NNNN')
        page = notebook.add('OOOO')
        page = notebook.add('PPPP')
        page = notebook.add('QQQQ')
        page = notebook.add('RRRR')       
        notebook.setnaturalsize()

######################################################################

# Create demo in root window for testing.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    Pmw.initialise(root)
    root.title(title)

    widget = Demo(root)
    exitButton = MyButton(root, text = 'Exit', command = root.destroy)
    exitButton.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Also is the image should be in .ico format or any other format is also applicable?

Attached the snapshot of the required style (marked with red). 
[image]).

Comment: It needs to be in `gif` or `png`. Use a `tk.PhotoImage` and just pack it.

Comment: Can you just tell me the format how to send. Because when i passed command like photo = PhotoImage(file="image.gif"), it didnt work. Also in that position is not specified as i needed (top right)

Comment: can anyone help me on how to insert image over the GUI screen??